# I am trying to order a string array

Tags: python

I have a 2d list, in the first part I have a string which represents the measurement number while the 2nd part represents the corresponding numerical measurement. I have attached the list below, and python seems to have ordered it 1,10,11,...,2,3,4 etc.

My question is how do I get it in chronological order? So that PI_1.txt is followed by PI_2.txt and not PI_10.txt

```
  ['PI_1.txt', 1004.1]
  ['PI_10.txt', 1104.8]
  ['PI_11.txt', 1115.3]
  ['PI_12.txt', 1104.7]
  ['PI_2.txt', 1019.1]
  ['PI_3.txt', 1062.3]
  ['PI_4.txt', 1239.6]
  ['PI_5.txt', 1143.2]
  ['PI_6.txt', 1139.3]
  ['PI_7.txt', 1131.3]
  ['PI_8.txt', 1130.9]
  ['PI_9.txt', 1108.9]
```

The list is above to make my description a bit simpler.

Thank you!

p.s. I can't change the filenames so they are just integers, as part of my code uses a selection based on whether or not "PI" is included in the filename

Comment: It's ordered lexicographically, because your measurement numbers are part of a string. You can find a good explanation for this here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/why-do-some-sorting-methods-sort-by-1-10-2-3/127644. To solve your problem, you'll need some kind of natural sort: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort

Comment: @jarmod Did you test this?  Try `x = ['PI_10.txt', 'PI_3.txt', 'PI_1.txt']` and then `x.sort()` and you'll see how Python orders it by default.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, Python will sort it that way if you call `sort()` on the populated list. There was no clear indication (such as actual code) that the OP populated the list a certain way and then called sort() on it but, fair comment, one could assume that (but I always prefer to see actual code, rather than assume something).

Comment: Aside from a custom sort, if you're going to index between 10 and 99 filenames then it's simple to make your index format `%02d` rather than `%d` (or for a range 0-999, use `%03d`). Then you essentially get sorting for free with `list.sort()`.

Comment: Thank you all for the help !!

Answer (score 2):

You could sort with a key:

```
listy.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0].split('.')[0].split('_')[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort the list in-place (as opposed to returning a sorted copy of the list) and the files are consistently named, you can use the following code which uses a key function to determine the order.

```py
data = [
    ['PI_1.txt', 1004.1],
    ['PI_10.txt', 1104.8],
    ['PI_11.txt', 1115.3],
    ['PI_12.txt', 1104.7],
    ['PI_2.txt', 1019.1],
    ['PI_3.txt', 1062.3],
    ['PI_4.txt', 1239.6],
    ['PI_5.txt', 1143.2],
    ['PI_6.txt', 1139.3],
    ['PI_7.txt', 1131.3],
    ['PI_8.txt', 1130.9],
    ['PI_9.txt', 1108.9]
]


data.sort(key=lambda d: int(d[0][3:-4]))
```

This code accesses the first item in the sublist, selects everything between the 3rd and last 4 characters, converts it to an integer, and then uses that value to order the 2-d list.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of task, I like to use the `natsort` library to handle naturally sorting the numbers with `operator.itemgetter` to help with identifying the element by which the nested list should be sorted.   With that all together, you can easily sort your 2D list like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from operator import itemgetter
from natsort import natsorted
from pprint import pprint as pp

d = [['PI_1.txt', 1004.1],
     ['PI_10.txt', 1104.8],
     ['PI_11.txt', 1115.3],
     ['PI_12.txt', 1104.7],
     ['PI_2.txt', 1019.1],
     ['PI_3.txt', 1062.3],
     ['PI_4.txt', 1239.6],
     ['PI_5.txt', 1143.2],
     ['PI_6.txt', 1139.3],
     ['PI_7.txt', 1131.3],
     ['PI_8.txt', 1130.9],
     ['PI_9.txt', 1108.9]]

print('Before: ')
pp(d)

print('\nAfter: ')
d = natsorted(d, key=itemgetter(0))
pp(d)
```

The resultant output looks like this:

```
Before:
[['PI_1.txt', 1004.1],
 ['PI_10.txt', 1104.8],
 ['PI_11.txt', 1115.3],
 ['PI_12.txt', 1104.7],
 ['PI_2.txt', 1019.1],
 ['PI_3.txt', 1062.3],
 ['PI_4.txt', 1239.6],
 ['PI_5.txt', 1143.2],
 ['PI_6.txt', 1139.3],
 ['PI_7.txt', 1131.3],
 ['PI_8.txt', 1130.9],
 ['PI_9.txt', 1108.9]]

After:
[['PI_1.txt', 1004.1],
 ['PI_2.txt', 1019.1],
 ['PI_3.txt', 1062.3],
 ['PI_4.txt', 1239.6],
 ['PI_5.txt', 1143.2],
 ['PI_6.txt', 1139.3],
 ['PI_7.txt', 1131.3],
 ['PI_8.txt', 1130.9],
 ['PI_9.txt', 1108.9],
 ['PI_10.txt', 1104.8],
 ['PI_11.txt', 1115.3],
 ['PI_12.txt', 1104.7]]
```